# Deeper understanding of Isaiah 40:20 "..who is too impoverished for such an offering...seeks...a skillful craftsman...To prepare an idol..."

Tags: isaiah, idolatry

> Isaiah 40:18-21
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 18 To whom then will you liken God?
> Or what likeness will you compare with Him?
> 19 As for the [a]idol, a craftsman casts it,
> A goldsmith plates it with gold,
> And a silversmith fashions chains of silver.
> 20 He who is too impoverished for such an offering
> Selects a tree that does not rot;
> He seeks out for himself a skillful craftsman
> To [b]prepare [c]an idol that will not totter.
>
> 21 Do you not know? Have you not heard?
> Has it not been declared to you from the beginning?
> Have you not understood from the foundations of the earth?

> 40:18-21 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 18 וְאֶל־מִ֖י תְּדַמְּי֣וּן
> אֵ֑ל וּמַה־דְּמ֖וּת תַּ֥עַרְכוּ לֽוֹ׃
>
> 19 הַפֶּ֙סֶל֙ נָסַ֣ךְ חָרָ֔שׁ וְצֹרֵ֖ף בַּזָּהָ֣ב יְרַקְּעֶ֑נּוּ
> וּרְתֻק֥וֹת כֶּ֖סֶף צוֹרֵֽף׃
>
> 20 הַֽמְסֻכָּ֣ן תְּרוּמָ֔ה עֵ֥ץ לֹֽא־יִרְקַ֖ב יִבְחָ֑ר חָרָ֤שׁ חָכָם֙
> יְבַקֶּשׁ־ל֔וֹ לְהָכִ֥ין פֶּ֖סֶל לֹ֥א יִמּֽוֹט׃
>
> 21 הֲל֤וֹא תֵֽדְעוּ֙ הֲל֣וֹא תִשְׁמָ֔עוּ הֲל֛וֹא הֻגַּ֥ד מֵרֹ֖אשׁ
> לָכֶ֑ם הֲלוֹא֙ הֲבִ֣ינֹתֶ֔ם מוֹסְד֖וֹת הָאָֽרֶץ׃

The overall theme behind Isaiah 40 is about emphasizing God's greatness.  Furthermore, Isaiah 40 rhetorically challenges anyone or anything to do things that God does in order to drive the point of God's greatness.

In Isaiah 40:19, the scripture condescendingly treats man-made idols.  However, in Isaiah 40:20, it strangely mentions the poor resorting to using whatever material they can afford to create idols.

I did cursorily read through the various commentaries on biblehub ( https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/40-20.htm ), but I found most
of them difficult to understand.

Essentially, is it Isaiah 40:20 saying that even the poor, despite the
fact that they have very little or nothing, are still so depraved that
they create man-made idols for themselves by finding whatever materials that they can get their hands on?  In other words, even the poor who have nothing can fail to look up to The God of Israel who can be worshipped, and sought after without any sort of idol statue being set up.

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 40:18-20 reinforces the general theme of this poem, which that God is absolutely transcendent. "To whom then will you liken God? Or what likeness will you compare with Him?" Isaiah emphasizes that any attempt to portray God with visible images will always fail. This is the case whether they are cast from bronze, richly plated with gold, made from costly hardwood trees, or carved from the cheapest wood.

Isaiah mentions those who can't afford costly materials as a way of reinforcing the point that, regardless of artistry and expense, images and idols cannot begin to describe the majesty of God.  The poor and the rich alike are incapable of creating a true image of God.

**Conclusion**: the deeper meaning of this text is found in its teaching of God's transcendence. No matter how skilled the craftsman or how costly the materials, any attempt to portray God through a visible image fails absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Isa 40:20 essentially attempts to compare the all-powerful Jehovah with a mute, man-made idol of wood covered in gold with chains. The thrust of the comparison is show that such a comparison is embarrassing because it alludes to the great idol of Dagon recounted in 1 Sam 5:3, 4

> **1** After the Philistines had captured the ark of God, they took it from Ebenezer to Ashdod, **2**carried it into the temple of Dagon, and
> set it beside his statue.
>
> **3 When the people of Ashdod got up early the next morning, there was Dagon, fallen on his face before the ark of the LORD. So they took
> Dagon and returned him to his place. 4 But when they got up early the
> next morning, there was Dagon, fallen on his face before the ark of
> the LORD, with his head and his hands broken off and lying on the
> threshold. Only the torso remained.**
>
> **5** That is why, to this day, the priests of Dagon and all who enter the temple of Dagon in Ashdod do not step on the threshold.

The idol that "topples" or "totters" shows that such mute, blind, immobile, senseless idols are nothing compared to the omnipotent God of heaven.  Indeed, with unabashed irony, Isaiah continues this "embarrassing" comparison of Jehovah to mute, blind idols in the next chapter by asking of an idol -

> Isa 41:23 - tell us what the future holds, so we may know that you are
> gods. Do something, whether good or bad, so that we will be dismayed
> and filled with fear.

Isaiah then concludes this part of his arguement with:

> Isa 41:24 - But you are less than nothing and your works are utterly
> worthless; whoever chooses you is detestable.